# Why is my jQuery code not working?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Well I know the code works because I am using it on three other pages and it works fine, however I have moved on to make a mobile version of my website. Basically, the code is used to  login in realtime. It serializes the users data, displays a "Logging in" message and then sends an ajax request to a file. The contents of the response from that file then replace the login message and depending on the situation, different things happen. I directly ported the code over from a working example and now, despite many changes to the code, the jquery does not seem to be firing at all. Here is my jquery code:

```
function login() {
    var dataString = $('#login_form').serialize();
    console.log(dataString);
    $(".menu_login_form").html("<center>Logging in...</center>");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../include/actions/login.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $(".menu_login_form").html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
  $("#login_form").on("submit", login);
```

And here is my html code:

```
<div class="menu_login_form">
  <form id="login_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style=""><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked="checked" style="margin:0;margin-right:10px;margin-top:-2.5px"><span>Remember Me</span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login..." id="login_form_btn" class="btn">
  </form>
</div>
```

Does anybody know whats wrong here?

EDIT: I've got it working now, I just placed it in the wrong place - joeframbach I've accepted your answer as it was the only one there. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Use a web inspector, check the network tab. When you fire the form submit, it will make a network request. Check to see if it's going to the proper file location, and check the response you get from the server.

Comment: Well what's happening is the ajax request is not sending at all, the form is just submitting like any normal form (nothing shows up in the network tab, the page just refreshes).

Comment: How about some sanity checking. In the console, run `$("#login_form")` to make sure that exists. Run `$('#login_form').serialize()` to make sure that's sane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in the document-ready incantation. This tells jquery to wait until the page is fully loaded before doing anything.

```
$(function() {
function login() {
    var dataString = $('#login_form').serialize();
    console.log(dataString);
    $(".menu_login_form").html("<center>Logging in...</center>");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../include/actions/login.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $(".menu_login_form").html(html);
      }
    });
    return false;
};
$("#login_form").on("submit", login);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and thanks for reminding me of something I have forgotten to do, but that's not the issue (there was no change after using the suggested code).

Comment: If you have external content (such as images) that you need to populate your DOM prior to your script's runtime, you can use `$(window).load( handler_function );` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/